# Using Ruby fastercsv, want to break my files out by 1000 lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently doing this:

```
users = User.all()

users.each do |u|

 csv << .....

end
```

But my file is way to big, I want to break it out into 1K rows per file, and name the file like:

users_1-1000.csv
users_1001-2000.csv
.etc.

How can I do this, I don't want to mess up with off-by-one errors either!

Answer (score 3):

`find_in_batches` is perfect for this. By default, `find_in_batches` uses a `:batch_size` of 1000, so your code would look something like this:

```
count = 1
User.find_in_batches do |users|
  FasterCSV.open("filename-#{count}.csv",'w') do |csv|
    users.each { |u| csv << ... }
    count += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit and offset method of AR. And change the offset each time you generate a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
users = User.all

users.each_with_index do |u, i|
  csv << ...
end
```

and then you use the index to know when it's time to switch to a new file.

```
(i % 1000) == 0    #Open new file
(i % 1000) == 999  #Close existing file
```